# Connect to a database over a unix socket using SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, unix-socket

I'm trying to connect to my Cloud SQL DB using SQLAlchemy from my cloud function but I can't seem to work out the correct connection string.

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://$DB_USER:$_DB_PWD@/$DB_NAME?unix_socket=/cloudsql/$DB_INSTANCE
```

Which gives me the error:

```
pyscopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dns: invalid connection option "unix_socket"
```

What is the correct way to connect to a Postgresql 9.6 DB over a unix socket using `pyscopg2`?

Answer (score 22):

The special keyword needed here is `host`:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@/dbname?host=/path/to/db
```

Note that the path in `host` should be a path, not the socket file itself (psycopg2 assumes the socket has the standard naming convention `.s.PGSQL.5432`)

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#unix-domain-connections

Comment: For whatever reason this didn't work for me and I'm also facing the OP's issue.

Comment: Works for me, make sure not to add '.s.PGSQL.5432' at the end of the connection string only the directory it is in

Comment: I think you need `postgresql` instead of `postgres` currently (2021).

Comment: Even the linked documentation doesn't say explicitly where to put the port, trial and error for user "fred" connecting to db "big_db" via socket in "/tmp/big_db_sockets/.s.PGSQL.1234" seems to be:
postgresql://fred@:1234/big_db?host=/tmp/big_db_sockets

Comment: what is troubling is that the official docs show a `unix_sock` query param that causes pyscopg2 to crash... => https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#connect_to so I'm really glad I came across this thread !

Comment: The GCP documentation in terms of connecting to SQL instance gave one of the toughest time in my life. It's even worse than Docker docs. `unix_sock` is super misleading. Give us that Bard AI instead of docs :v

Comment: Note: if your socket has a different port, like `.s.PGSQL.5433` instead of `.s.PGSQL.5432`, add `?port=5433`.