# Python Bookshelf App giving error on deployment to GCP using postgresql cloud SQL DB

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

I am deploying the GCP Python Bookshelf application using postgresSQL cloud SQL DB.
My app is not running properly. The error log is as seen in the image below.

[image: deployment error]

I have done all the required changes in app.yaml, requirements.txt and config.py files.
The project is running fine locally using cloud-sql-proxy but not working properly in the deployed version. Could someone guide me how to resolve this?

My **env variables** in **app.yaml** are:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

#[START cloudsql_settings]
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "<my_project_id>:<region_name>:<cloudsql_instance>"
    # cloud_sql_instances: "your-cloudsql-connection-name"
#[END cloudsql_settings]
```

The **config.py** is:

```
import os

DATA_BACKEND = 'cloudsql'
PROJECT_ID = '<my_project_id>'
CLOUDSQL_USER = '<username>'
CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD = '<password>'
CLOUDSQL_DATABASE = '<db_name>'
CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME = '<my_project_id>:<region_name>:<cloudsql_instance>'
LOCAL_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@127.0.0.1:3306/{database}').format(
        user=CLOUDSQL_USER, password=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD,
        database=CLOUDSQL_DATABASE)
LIVE_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    'postgres://{user}:{password}@localhost/{database}'
    '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{connection_name}').format(
        user=CLOUDSQL_USER, password=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD,
        database=CLOUDSQL_DATABASE, connection_name=CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME)

if os.environ.get('GAE_INSTANCE'):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = LIVE_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
else:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = LOCAL_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

The **requirements.txt** is:

```
Flask>=1.0.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
psycopg2==2.8.4
PyMySQL==0.9.2
Flask-PyMongo>=2.0.0
oauth2client==4.1.2
PyMongo==3.7.2
six==1.11.0
```

The **detailed error** is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2275, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 481, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 125, in connect
    dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 174, in make_dsn
    parse_dsn(dsn)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "unix_socket"
```

Comment: can you paste the actual detail error instead of image?

Comment: also please provide the env_variables in app.yaml file

Comment: @JohnSnow Please have a look, I have updated the question.

Comment: What is the contents of your `config.py` file as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql)? Specifically what is `[DATA_BACKEND]` and `[CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME]`?

Comment: @DustinIngram Yes it is as mentioned in the link. DATA_BACKEND is cloudsql & CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME is my cloudsql_instance name. Edited the question as well with required data. Please have a look and help me out.

Comment: I think LIVE_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    'postgres://{user}:{password}@localhost/{database}'
    '?host=/cloudsql/{connection_name}'). You should replace unix_socket with host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIVE_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ( 'postgres://{user}:{password}@localhost/{database}' '?host=/cloudsql/{connection_name}').

I had to **replace unix_socket with host** in LIVE_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI. Also only postgres was required.

I don't know if it is required but I also added Cloud SQL Client role to my app engine service account.
Thanks all for your help guys.

Comment: Glad you made it work, I was about to link you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967660/connect-to-a-database-over-a-unix-socket-using-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@/db?unix_socket=/cloudsql/project-name:region:dbinstance`?

Try using `postgres://` instead of `postgresql+psycopg2//:`

The more info you provide us, about your connection or anything the more we can attempt to help you. Is this the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres) you based yourself on?

**EDIT:**

Hey,if you double checked that every connection is OK, please add Cloud SQL Client role to your app engine service account and let me know if that fixed it for you.

Comment: Let me try that. Yes I used this tutorial. Also this is the link for Bookshelf app cloud sql tutorial:  https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/users/11928097/stefan-g] I tried your solution. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add in your config.py without revealing any sensible information please?

Comment: Have a look at the edit in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I added the role as well, still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this syntax works for me on an App Engine deployment that uses a PostgreSQL instance in Cloud SQL, using the pg8000 driver:

```py
connection_string = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
   drivername="postgres+pg8000",
   username=username,
   password=password,
   database=database,
   query="unix_sock": "/cloudsql/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(instance),
)

connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    connection_string,
    pool_size=50,
    max_overflow=2,
    pool_timeout=30,
    pool_recycle=1800,
)
```